# Sequelize .sync function hangs: emitter from serial.klass

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I've pulled an application down from our staging environment which is running perfectly on the staging computer, but locally it hangs on the `sequelize.sync` function.

The application doesn't even reaching the "Listening on port..."

I've logged through the sync function within [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) and found that this is where it is stuck:

*(lines 79 - 88 in query-chainer.js)*

```
var emitter = serial.klass[serial.method].apply(serial.klass, serial.params)

emitter.success(function(result) {
  self.serialResults[serialCopy.indexOf(serial)] = result

  if (serial.options.success) {
    serial.options.success(serial.klass, onSuccess)
  } else {
    onSuccess()
  }
}).error(onError)
```

This function does not return into either `success` or `error`. I shouldn't have to make any changes to their code since I know their library is working--I have a local copy that works that we're refactoring and I just needed the staging copy to do a quick change for production while we finish the refactor.

What could have changed to cause this issue? It almost seems like it could be a connection issue?

I have verified that the host is `localhost` with port of `5432`. Correct `username`, `password`, and `dbName`. All fed through:

```
sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.dbName, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: config.db.host,
    port: config.db.port,
    logging: false,
    define: sequelizeMethods
});
```

I have also confirmed that the `postgresql-x64-9.2 - PostgreSQL Server 9.2` service is running.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Or ways to get additional information?

Answer (score 1):

Can you connect using `psql -d <dbname> -h localhost -U <username> -W`?

Is `pg@~2.0.0` installed? If so, is it installed on your machine or just pulled in via `node_modules`?

Have you tried `npm install sequelize-postgres` and using:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize-postgres').sequelize
var postgres  = require('sequelize-postgres').postgres

var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  dialect: 'postgres'
})
```

Is there any log output from postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say why with the information you provided. I guess you should look into

```
serial.klass[serial.method]
```

I'd guess that there should be something like

```
emitter.emit('success');
```

Probably this is not happening and an error is also not occurring. Hope I could help.